# Perl do...while and last command

Tags: perl

I've just encountered some very weird behavior that I really can't explain:

```
do {
    my $qry = $self->getHTMLQuery(undef, $mech->content());
    next if (!defined($qry));

    push(
        @prods,
        map { 'http://www.XXXXYYYX.com'.$_->attr('href') }
            $qry->query('div.prodInfo div.prodInfoBox a.prodLink.GridItemLink')
    );

    $qry->delete();
    $TEST++;

    last if ($TEST >= 10);

} while(eval { $mech->follow_link(class => 'jump next') });

print "WHILE ENDED\n";
```

The code above never prints "WHILE ENDED" even though it does seem to go out of the while loop when `$TEST` >= 10.

But the following code does print "WHILE ENDED":

```
do {
    my $qry = $self->getHTMLQuery(undef, $mech->content());
    next if (!defined($qry));

    push(
        @prods,
        map { 'http://www.XXXXYYYX.com'.$_->attr('href') }
            $qry->query('div.prodInfo div.prodInfoBox a.prodLink.GridItemLink')
    );

    $qry->delete();
    $TEST++;

} while(eval { $mech->follow_link(class => 'jump next') } && $TEST <= 10);

print "WHILE ENDED\n";
```

In both tests, the initial value of `$TEST` is 0.

Is the behavior of `last` in `do...while` different than in `for` and `while {...}`?

Comment: I assume the second time you say "the code above", you actually mean "the code *below*"

Comment: It’s even worse when the `do {...} while` loop is inside a real `while {...}`. You try to use `last` and `next` inside the inner loop but they affect the outer loop. It’s a WTF situation until you realize this Perl trap. BTW, it’s listed in `perltrap` doc.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A `do` block with a looping modifier doesn't count as a real loop as far as `next`, `last`, and `redo` are concerned.  This is mentioned in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers), where you'll find the tip Schwern mentioned about surrounding it with a bare block to make `last` work.  But that won't work with `next`, because a bare block is only executed once, so `next` acts like `last`.  To make `next` work, you can put the bare block *inside* the `do`, but then `last` will act like `next`.

If you need both `next` and `last` to work with a `do ... while`, the easiest way is to use an infinite loop with the real condition in a `continue` block.  These 2 loops are equivalent, except that the second is a real loop, so it works with `next` & `last`:

```
do { ... } while condition;
while (1) { ... } continue { last unless condition };
```

Answer (score 21):

From [perldoc -f last](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html):

> "last" cannot be used to exit a block that returns a value such as
>   "eval {}", "sub {}" or "do {}"

Answer (score 17):

TLP is right.  The standard work around for this (I just hit it myself) is to wrap the do/while in a bare block which, counter-intuitively, does respect loop controls.

```
{ do {
    last;
} while 1; }
```

The block outside will catch `last`.  If you want to handle `next` you have to put the bloc inside.

```
do {{
    next;
}} while 1;
```

The block inside will catch `next`.

Unfortunately you can't do both.

Comment: That'll fix the `last`, but it won't fix the `next`.  With a bare block, those two are equivalent (since bare blocks are only executed once).

Comment: @cjm Good catch.  And I discovered you can't do both. :-(

Comment: Well, you _could_, but you'd have to put a label on the outer block and then use `last LABEL`.  And that's just asking for bugs, because if you forget the label and type just `last`, it'll act like `next` instead.