# How do you rotate a single layer of a matrix by n places?

Tags: arrays, perl, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

I have read all the questions on stack overflow regarding rotating matrices
and none of them address anything other than transposing or rotating by 90 or 180 degrees in either direction of either single layers or the entire matrices.

I have already answered the question as far as accomplishing it but I am looking for fast and/or 'in place' methods, preferably, but any methods
other than the one I have given would be nice to see as well if only for
educational purposes. My example is in Perl 5 but as long as your intentions are clear, most any language should be acceptable.

The matrix used in my example is as follows

```
# 2D array @arr has 3 layers.
# @arr is 
#         0 1 2 3 4 5
#         a b c d e f
#         5 4 3 2 1 0
#         9 8 7 6 5 4
#         f e d c b a
#         4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Goal->Rotate middle layer 2 places clockwise to get the following...

Notice how the top left corner of the middle layer, 'b c', has moved 2 places to the right and the '8 4' from the middle left side is now where the 'b c' was.

```
# Rotated @arr is 
#         0 1 2 3 4 5
#         a 8 4 b c f
#         5 e 3 2 d 0
#         9 d 7 6 e 4 
#         f c b 5 1 a
#         4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Currently I have been doing something along the lines of this, which is admittedly, terribly slow. Especially on many large arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

# Coordinates are $arr[$row][$col]
my @arr;
$arr[0][0]='0'; $arr[0][1]='1'; $arr[0][2]='2'; $arr[0][3]='3'; $arr[0][4]='4'; $arr[0][5]='5';
$arr[1][0]='a'; $arr[1][1]='b'; $arr[1][2]='c'; $arr[1][3]='d'; $arr[1][4]='e'; $arr[1][5]='f';
$arr[2][0]='5'; $arr[2][1]='4'; $arr[2][2]='3'; $arr[2][3]='2'; $arr[2][4]='1'; $arr[2][5]='0';
$arr[3][0]='9'; $arr[3][1]='8'; $arr[3][2]='7'; $arr[3][3]='6'; $arr[3][4]='5'; $arr[3][5]='4';
$arr[4][0]='f'; $arr[4][1]='e'; $arr[4][2]='d'; $arr[4][3]='c'; $arr[4][4]='b'; $arr[4][5]='a';
$arr[5][0]='4'; $arr[5][1]='5'; $arr[5][2]='6'; $arr[5][3]='7'; $arr[5][4]='8'; $arr[5][5]='9';

# Print matrix
print_matrix(@arr);

# Extract layer 2
my $target_layer=2;
my $layer_two=extract_layer($target_layer,@arr);

# From the top left corner of the layer, it is as follows
# bcde15bcde84
print "\n$layer_two\n";

# Rotate layer 2 clockwise 2 places
$layer_two=rotate_layer_cl($layer_two,2);

# 84bcde15bcde
print "$layer_two\n\n";

# Replace layer 2 in the same way
@arr=replace_layer($target_layer,$layer_two,@arr);

# Print again
print_matrix(@arr);

### Sub functions ###
# Extract layer by walking around it's coordinates like so
# [1,1]-[1,4]  Top(left->right)
# [2,4]-[4,4]  Right(top->bottom)
# [4,3]-[4,1]  Bottom(right->left)
# [3,1]-[2,1]  Left(bottom->top)
sub extract_layer {
    my ($layer_cnt,@matrix)=@_;
    my $width=scalar(@matrix);
    my $layer_width=$width-$layer_cnt;
    # layer_cnt=2
    # width=6
    # layer_width=4
    my $layer;
    for my $col ( $layer_cnt-1..$layer_width ) {
        $layer.=$matrix[$layer_cnt-1][$col];
    }
    for my $row ( $layer_cnt..$layer_width ) {
        $layer.=$matrix[$row][$layer_width];
    }
    my $cnt=$layer_width-1;
    while ( $cnt >= $layer_cnt-1 ) {
        $layer.=$matrix[$layer_width][$cnt];
        $cnt--;
    }
    $cnt=$layer_width-1;
    while ( $cnt >= $layer_cnt ) {
        $layer.=$matrix[$cnt][$layer_cnt-1];
        $cnt--;
    }
    return $layer;
}

# Shift input to the right by $n places, wrapping around.
sub rotate_layer_cl {
    my $n=$_[1];
    my $buf=substr($_[0],length($_[0])-$n,$n);
    return $buf.substr($_[0],0,length($_[0])-$n);
}

# Replace each char from the rotated layer.
sub replace_layer {
    my ($layer_cnt,$layer,@matrix)=@_;
    my $width=scalar(@matrix);
    my $layer_width=$width-$layer_cnt;
    # layer_cnt=2
    # width=6
    # layer_width=4
    my $slot=0;
    for my $col ( $layer_cnt-1..$layer_width ) {
        $matrix[$layer_cnt-1][$col]=substr($layer,$slot,1);
        $slot++;
    }
    for my $row ( $layer_cnt..$layer_width ) {
        $matrix[$row][$layer_width]=substr($layer,$slot,1);
        $slot++;
    }
    my $cnt=$layer_width-1;
    while ( $cnt >= $layer_cnt-1 ) {
        $matrix[$layer_width][$cnt]=substr($layer,$slot,1);
        $slot++;
        $cnt--;
    }
    $cnt=$layer_width-1;
    while ( $cnt >= $layer_cnt ) {
        $matrix[$cnt][$layer_cnt-1]=substr($layer,$slot,1);
        $slot++;
        $cnt--;
    }
    return @matrix;
}

# Prints given matrix
sub print_matrix {
    foreach my $row (@_) {
        my $cnt=0;
        foreach my $char (@$row) {
            print $char; $cnt++;
            if ( $cnt == scalar(@_) ) {
                print "\n";
            } else {
                print " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code outputs as follows,

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4
f e d c b a
4 5 6 7 8 9

bcde15bcde84
84bcde15bcde

0 1 2 3 4 5
a 8 4 b c f
5 e 3 2 d 0
9 d 7 6 e 4
f c b 5 1 a
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

which shows the array before rotating the middle layer, the middle layer as a string, the middle layer shifted as a string, and the final resulting array after the middle layer has been rotated 2 places to the right.

-----EDIT-----

So far, the fastest method I have found is to not actually use the full 2D array but to put the block in a regular array like...

```
my @hex_ary=('1234', '5678', '90ab', 'cdef');
```

Then create the layer string and shift it the same way my original example shows.

However, because they are strings, I only need to "walk" up and down the sides. The top and bottom are simply referenced as...

```
my $top=substr($hex_ary[0],0,3);
```

and

```
my $bot=reverse(substr($hex_ary[3],0,3));
```

for the outer layer in this small 4x4 array, while the sides are itered through with

```
my $right_side_char=substr($hex_ary[$top_row-$i],-1);
my $left_side_char=substr($hex_ary[$bot_row+$i],0,1);
```

Doing so increases performance approx. 100% from the 2D method because the number of slices taken from the array is then half+2.

Maybe someone with a better grasp of C could create something more efficient. I feel like Perl is just only capable of so much sometimes.

Comment: One idea: can you express the rotation as a function `f(x,y)` i.e. the input `(x,y)` are the row/col index of each member in the middle layer and the output is the rotated position `(x',y')`?. Then the approach would be (1) make a copy of `@arr`, (2) loop over the middle layer members and place each member in the copy based on the output of `f()`.

Comment: I guess you would also need a function `members(ring_identifier)` which returns an array with `[x,y]` entries of all members of ring `ring_identifier`. That would be the source for the `for my($x, $y) (@{ $members }) { ... }` loop.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this but wasn't exactly sure how to implement it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad we could be of help, I definitely enjoyed working on this. Please remember to up-vote on the answers and accept the one you like best.

Answer (score 1):

The approach in a nutshell:

- copy array
- calculate list of members (row, column) for the ring
- loop over list index

  - read from member[index] in original array
  - write to member[(index + shift) % ring length] in copy array
- Right shift by N places: shift ==  N
- Left shift by N places:  shift == -N

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub dump_array($$) {
    my($label, $array) = @_;
    print "${label}:\n";
    foreach my $row (@{ $array }) {
        print join(" ", @{ $row }), "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}

sub copy_array($) {
    my($array) = @_;
    my @copy;
    foreach my $row (@{ $array }) {
        push(@copy, [ @{ $row } ]);
    }
    return(\@copy);
}

sub ring_index_to_row_col($$$$$) {
    my($N, $ring, $total, $length, $index) = @_;
    my($row, $col);

    if ($index < $length) {
        # top row, left to right
        $row = 0;
        $col = $index;
    } elsif ($index < 2 * $length - 2) {
        # top to bottom, right row
        $row = $index - $length + 1;
        $col = $N - 1 - 2 * $ring;
    } elsif ($index < 3 * $length - 2) {
        # bottom row, right to left
        $row = $N - 1 - 2 * $ring;
        #$col = $length - 1 - ($index - 2 * $length + 2);
        $col = -$index + 3 * $length - 3;
    } else {
        # bottom to top, left row
        #$row = $total - 1 - $index + 1;
        $row = $total - $index;
        $col = 0;
    }

    #print "${index}\t of ${total}\t-> ${row}, ${col}\n";

    # shift $length x length array to offset ($ring, $ring)
    return([$row + $ring, $col + $ring]);
}

sub ring_members($$) {
    my($N, $ring) = @_;
    my @list;

    # @TODO: odd N?
    #
    # Examples for N == 6
    #   0   -> 2*6 + 2*4 = 20
    #   1   -> 2*4 + 2*2 = 12
    #   2   -> 2*2 + 2*0 =  4
    #
    # Examples for N == 5
    #   0   -> 2*5 + 2*3
    #   1   -> 2*3 + 2*1
    #   2   -> 1
    #
    # Examples for N == 4
    #   0   -> 2*4 + 2*2 = 12
    #   1   -> 2*2 + 2*0 =  4
    my $length  = $N - 2 * $ring;
    my $members = 4 *  $N - 8 * $ring - 4;

    foreach my $index (0..$members-1) {
        push(@list, ring_index_to_row_col($N, $ring, $members, $length, $index));
    }

    return(\@list);
}

sub rotate_array_ring(\@$$) {
    my($source, $ring, $shift) = @_;

    # Sanity check. @TODO is the check correct for odd N?
    my $N              = @{ $source };
    die "ERROR: invalid ring '${ring}' for 2D array of size $N!\n"
        unless $ring < ($N / 2);

    my $copy   = copy_array($source);

    my $list   = ring_members($N, $ring);
    my $length = @{ $list };

    foreach my $index (0..$length-1) {
        my($row,   $col)   = @{ $list->[ $index                     ] };
        my($s_row, $s_col) = @{ $list->[($index + $shift) % $length ] };

        $copy->[$s_row]->[$s_col] = $source->[$row]->[$col];
    }

    return($copy);
}

my @source;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    push(@source, [ split(/\s+/, $_) ]);
}
dump_array('SOURCE', \@source);

dump_array('SHIFT 1 RING 0', rotate_array_ring(@source, 0, 1));
dump_array('SHIFT 1 RING 1', rotate_array_ring(@source, 1, 1));
dump_array('SHIFT 1 RING 2', rotate_array_ring(@source, 2, 1));
dump_array('SHIFT 2 RING 0', rotate_array_ring(@source, 0, 2));
dump_array('SHIFT 2 RING 1', rotate_array_ring(@source, 1, 2));
dump_array('SHIFT 2 RING 2', rotate_array_ring(@source, 2, 2));

exit 0;

__DATA__
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4
f e d c b a
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Example output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
SOURCE:
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
5 4 3 2 1 0
9 8 7 6 5 4
f e d c b a
4 5 6 7 8 9

SHIFT 1 RING 0:
a 0 1 2 3 4
5 b c d e 5
9 4 3 2 1 f
f 8 7 6 5 0
4 e d c b 4
5 6 7 8 9 a

SHIFT 1 RING 1:
0 1 2 3 4 5
a 4 b c d f
5 8 3 2 e 0
9 e 7 6 1 4
f d c b 5 a
4 5 6 7 8 9

SHIFT 1 RING 2:
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
5 4 7 3 1 0
9 8 6 2 5 4
f e d c b a
4 5 6 7 8 9

SHIFT 2 RING 0:
5 a 0 1 2 3
9 b c d e 4
f 4 3 2 1 5
4 8 7 6 5 f
5 e d c b 0
6 7 8 9 a 4

SHIFT 2 RING 1:
0 1 2 3 4 5
a 8 4 b c f
5 e 3 2 d 0
9 d 7 6 e 4
f c b 5 1 a
4 5 6 7 8 9

SHIFT 2 RING 2:
0 1 2 3 4 5
a b c d e f
5 4 6 7 1 0
9 8 2 3 5 4
f e d c b a
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**OPTIMIZATION:** don't copy the whole array, but

1. use `$list` to copy out the ring members to a list and then
2. loop over that list to place them into the shifted position back into the array.

I.e. two loops instead of one:

```perl
my $list   = ring_members($N, $ring);
my $length = @{ $list };

# in-place approach
my @members;
foreach my $index (0..$length-1) {
    my($row, $col) = @{ $list->[ $index ] };
    push(@members, $source->[$row]->[$col]);
}
foreach my $index (0..$length-1) {
    my($row, $col) = @{ $list->[ ($index + $shift) % $length ] };
    $source->[$row]->[$col] = $members[$index];
}

return($source);
```

**OPTIMIZATION 2:** if you have a sequence of operations that you need to apply to a set of same-sized 2D arrays, then you could pre-generate them and process them over-and-over using a function:

```perl
my $N     = 6; # all arrays are of same size
my @rings = (
    ring_members($N, 0),
    ring_members($N, 1),
    ring_members($N, 2),
);
my @operations = (
    { ring => $rings[0], shift =>  1 },
    { ring => $rings[1], shift => -1 },
    { ring => $rings[2], shift =>  2 },
    # ...
)

# apply one operation in-place on array
sub apply_operation($$) {
    my($array, $operation) = @_;
    my $list               = $operation->{ring};
    my $shift              = $operation->{shift};
    my $length             = @{ $list };

    my @members;
    foreach my $index (0..$length-1) {
        my($row, $col) = @{ $list->[ $index ] };
        push(@members, $array->[$row]->[$col]);
    }
    foreach my $index (0..$length-1) {
        my($row, $col) = @{ $list->[ ($index + $shift) % $length ] };
        $array->[$row]->[$col] = $members[$index];
    }
}

# apply operation sequence in-place on array
sub apply_operations($$) {
    my($array, $operations) = @_;

    foreach my $operation (@{ $operations }) {
        apply_operation($array, $operation);    
    }
}

apply_operations(\@array1, \@operations);
apply_operations(\@array2, \@operations);
apply_operations(\@array3, \@operations);
...
```

**OPTIMIZATION 3:** don't make a copy of the complete group in the in-place approach, but only of those members which would be overwritten by the roation. I.e. use 3 loops:

1. copy the first or last `$shift` members (depending on the rotation direction) to `@cache` array.
2. do a straight copy for the other `$length - abs($shift)` members.
3. copy `@cache` members to their rotated places.

**OPTIMIZATION 4:** don't use a 2D array (AoA) but a 1D array with `$N * $N` entries. I.e.

- instead of `ring_index_to_row_col()` returning `[$row, $col]` you would have `ring_index_to_array_index()` returning `$row * $N + $col`.
- array accesses `->[$row]->[$col]` would be replaced with `->[$array_index]`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is definitely the most intricate answer and thorough response. In a 1KB array test it is only 1/3 the speed of my example.

Comment: If you use the in-place approach on a large array it might improve performance when you replace the `push(@members, ...` with (a) before the first loop `$#members = $length - 1`, i.e. pre-allocate the array, and (b) in the first loop `$members[$index] = ...`

Comment: Added 3rd & 4th optimization idea.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of my method is to use a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) (well, I'm using a Perl array here because I couldn't find a suitable module, but it's far from ideal) containing `n` elements (where `n` is the number of places you want to rotate your layer by), and to iterate through each elements of the layer, and each time, `push` its value to the queue, and replace it with the first element of the queue.

This is what the sub `rotate_matrix` does.
 - `$i` and `$j` represent the index of the current element of the layer. Their values goes between `$target_layer` and `$max_i`/`$max_j`; the sub `next_ij` takes care of computing the index of the next element of the layer.
 - The interesting stuffs happen inside the `while(1)` loop (which is actually a `do...while`; but `do while` loops are [a bit special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897015/perl-do-while-and-last-command) in Perl): the value of the current element is pushed to the queue, and, if their are more than `$n` elements in the queue (meaning that we have already pushed `$n` elements, representing the fact the we want to rotate by `$n`), we replace its value by the first element of the queue. The `continue` block takes care of incrementing `$i` and `$j`, and stops the loop once we come back to the first element of the layer.
- Once this is loop is done, the first `n` elements of the layer haven't been updated (because of this `next unless @queue > $n`), so we need to take care of that: this is the `while (@queue)` loop).

Complexity-wise, there is no need to copy the array. The memory usage is `O(n)` (the size of the queue). Time-wise, you loop once over each element of the layer, and each time, you `push` and `shift` from you queue (using a better datastructure, like a linked list, this would be `O(1)`, but with a Perl array, it's probably in the lines of `O(n)`; but probably amortized to `O(1)`), and compute the next index (`O(1)`). So you end up with a time complexity, you end up with `O(size of the layer to rotate)`.

A few caveats: if `$n` is greater than the number of elements in the layer, this won't work (but it can be fixed with a simple modulo). If you ask for a layer that isn't present in the matrix (like 4-th layer of a 2x2 matrix), weird stuffs will happen (but once again, it's easy to fix).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;


my @arr = ( [qw(0 1 2 3 4 5)],
            [qw(a b c d e f)],
            [qw(5 4 3 2 1 0)],
            [qw(9 8 7 6 5 4)],
            [qw(f e d c b a)],
            [qw(4 5 6 7 8 9)] );

print_matrix(@arr);

rotate_matrix(\@arr, 2, 2);
say "";

print_matrix(@arr);


sub rotate_matrix {
    my ($matrix, $target_layer, $n) = @_;
    --$target_layer; # I prefer a 0-indexed value
    # TODO: check that $target_layer < @$matrix/2
    # TODO: do something like $n = $n % (num of elements in layer)

    my @queue;
    my ($i, $j) = ($target_layer, $target_layer);
    my ($max_i, $max_j) = (@{$matrix->[0]}-$target_layer-1, @$matrix-$target_layer-1);

    while (1) { # Actually a do...while loop (see 'continue' block)
        push @queue, $matrix->[$i][$j];
        next unless @queue > $n; # Waiting to reach n-th element
        $matrix->[$i][$j] = shift @queue;
    } continue {
        ($i, $j) = next_ij($target_layer,$max_i,$max_j,$i,$j);
        # Stopping if we are back at the begining
        last if $i == $target_layer && $j == $target_layer;
    }

    # Emptying queue
    while (@queue) {
        $matrix->[$i][$j] = shift @queue;
        ($i, $j) = next_ij($target_layer,$max_i,$max_j,$i,$j);
    }


}

# Computes the index of the next element of the layer
sub next_ij {
    my ($target_layer, $max_i, $max_j, $i, $j) = @_;
    if ($j == $max_j) { # Last column
        if ($i == $max_i) { # Last row (bottom right -> going left)
            return ($i, $j-1);
        } else { # Not last row (somewhere on the right col -> going down)
            return ($i+1, $j);
        }
    } elsif ($j == $target_layer) { # First column
        if ($i == $target_layer) { # First row (top left -> going right)
            return ($i, $j+1);
        } else { # Not top row (somewhere on the left col -> going up)
            return ($i-1, $j);
        }
    } else { # Neither first nor last column
        if ($i == $target_layer) { # First row (somewhere on the top row -> going right)
            return ($i, $j+1);
        } else { # Last row (somewhere on the last row -> going left)
            return ($i, $j-1);
        }
    }
}



# Prints given matrix
sub print_matrix {
    foreach my $row (@_) {
        my $cnt=0;
        foreach my $char (@$row) {
            print $char; $cnt++;
            if ( $cnt == scalar(@_) ) {
                print "\n";
            } else {
                print " ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. I like it :) In practice, on a 1KB matrix it is almost identical performance to my original method.